# React - stuck on filtering JSON data based on whether object key exists

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

First post. I'm returning to web dev and programming after 10 years of being a network engineer, and I'm making a project app in React. I've run into some issues working with JSON data I've fetched from an API.

**What my code does:**
As I mentioned, I'm using React to create this web app. I have a Search.js component which takes a username input from a form and performs a fetch operation, querying the [PUBG API](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/introduction.html)  ((PLAYERUNKNOWNS Battlegrounds).

It then passes the JSON data it gets back via props to a Results.js function. Here's the code for that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.sass';
import '../index.css';

class Results extends Component {

render() {

    let content;

    if (this.props.loading) {
        content = <div className="results-container"><div className="results">
        <img src={require('../images/ajax-loader.gif')} /></div></div>
    } else {
        content =
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.props.mData.map((matches, index) => {
                return <div className="results-container"><div className="results" key={index}>
                        <p>{matches.attributes.stats.name}</p>

              </div></div>
        })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    }


return (
    <>
    {content}
    </>

)


    }
}

export default Results;
```

Here is an example of the JSON data that's being passed via props:

```
 "mData": [
    {
      "type": "participant",
      "id": "72b04727-0ab4-4016-9468-2e10a3dbdaeb",
      "attributes": {
        "stats": {
          "DBNOs": 1,
          "assists": 0,
          "boosts": 5,
          "damageDealt": 253.54834,
          "deathType": "byplayer",
          "headshotKills": 1,
          "heals": 13,
          "killPlace": 26,
          "killStreaks": 1,
          "kills": 1,
          "longestKill": 35.026,
          "name": "Pembo",
          "playerId": "account.75b1fc48f40b4043b1eb17f2d46a8e1d",
          "revives": 0,
          "rideDistance": 7201.147,
          "roadKills": 0,
          "swimDistance": 0,
          "teamKills": 0,
          "timeSurvived": 1673.926,
          "vehicleDestroys": 0,
          "walkDistance": 3010.6506,
          "weaponsAcquired": 4,
          "winPlace": 3
        },
        "actor": "",
        "shardId": "steam"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "participant",
      "id": "99481652-ec74-41b2-b3a3-fdab30c04b93",
      "attributes": {
        "stats": {
          "DBNOs": 1,
          "assists": 0,
          "boosts": 1,
          "damageDealt": 100,
          "deathType": "byplayer",
          "headshotKills": 0,
          "heals": 0,
          "killPlace": 42,
          "killStreaks": 1,
          "kills": 1,
          "longestKill": 11.017569,
          "name": "Mccarry79",
          "playerId": "account.e086fc7caef24e388b158cacb4dff538",
          "revives": 0,
          "rideDistance": 0,
          "roadKills": 0,
          "swimDistance": 0,
          "teamKills": 0,
          "timeSurvived": 330.793,
          "vehicleDestroys": 0,
          "walkDistance": 459.02472,
          "weaponsAcquired": 3,
          "winPlace": 26
        },
        "actor": "",
        "shardId": "steam"
      }
    },
```

All I'm trying to do is iterate over each object in the array and pull out the name value from attributes.stats.name, then display it on the page. The above code resulted in an error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

At this point I realised that some objects exist in this array which do not actually contain the attributes.stats.name property:

```
    {
      "type": "roster",
      "id": "a20c3b6c-5409-4bf6-9f04-58a08d5cd3b8",
      "attributes": {
        "stats": {
          "rank": 22,
          "teamId": 11
        },
        "won": "false",
        "shardId": "steam"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "team": "Object",
        "participants": "Object"
      }
    },
```

**Question 1:** is this the reason for the error I'm seeing? It's iterating through them all, then it hits one of the multiple objects without that property and errors?

**Question 2:** how do I fix this?

My first thought was that I need to filter out all the objects in the array without the property I'm looking for, so I researched that. I've tried various combinations of code, none of which have worked.

My current idea is that I want to use .filter() on the array, matching only objects which contain the key of attributes.stats.name. Nothing I've tried has managed to work, however. I've been working on this over the last few days and I'm stumped, so I'm asking for help.

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: are you adding new object to existing array?

Comment: A nice and easy way to check object before accessing them:
x && x.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.filter() sounds like a good method to achieve what you want in this case. The error you get (TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined) is because the "stats" property doesn't seem to exist (i.e is undefined).

A filter that checks for `stats` and `stats.name` might fix this. Something like this (`el` is short for element) (warning: untested code):

```
filteredArray = this.props.mData.filter(el => el.attributes.stats && el.attributes.stats.name);
```

If `el.attributes.stats` is falsy (undefined) it will return false immediately. If it exists, but the next check `el.attributes.stats.name` is falsy, it will return false. If `stats` exists and `stats.name` also exists, it will return true and the current `el` will be included in your results.

Then use `filteredArray.map()` in your jsx (instead of `this.props.mData.map()`) to show the data.

Comment: This worked and solved the issue. Thank you. I knew it had something to do with using .filter() but just didn't get the rest of the code right.

Comment: One question - using "el.attributes.stats && el.attributes.stats.name" works but 
just "el.attributes.stats.name" does not. Can you explain why this is, considering all objects in the array have el.attributes.stats present, but only some don't have .name. Why do we need to check if .stats exists first before checking .stats.name?

Comment: The answer to that is that some objects must have a missing "attributes.stats", otherwise you wouldn't get the error in the first place. The error message states "Cannot read property name of undefined". Undefined is referring to the stats property not the stats.name property.

Comment: Modify the code like this: `filteredArray = this.props.mData.filter(el => el.attributes.stats === undefined); console.log(filteredArray)`. And you'll see the objects that doesn't have attributes.stats present :)

Comment: Thanks, you were correct again! There was a sneaky object which didn't contain any stats that I hadn't noticed before. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: No problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
...

{this.props.mData && Array.isArray(this.props.mData) && this.props.mData.map((matches, index) => {
         return <div className="results-container">
                  <div className="results" key={index}>
                    <p>{matches.attributes.stats.name}</p>
...
```

Try this.

Comment: Please add explanation as to what and why have you changed.